# Convert negative index in Python to positive index

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm trying to find a way to get the index of an item in a list in Python given its negative index, including an index of 0.

For example with a list, *l* of size 4:

```
l[0]  # index 0
l[-1] # index 3
l[-2] # index 2
```

I have tried using

```
index = negative + len(l)
```

however this will not work when the index is `0`.

The only way I have found so far involves an `if/else` statement.

```
 index = 0 if negative == 0 else negative + len(l)
```

Is there a possible way to do this in Python without having to use an `if` statement?

*I am trying to store the index of the item so I can access it later, but I am being given indices starting from 0 and moving backwards through the list, and would like to convert them from negative to positive.*

Comment: do you only want to convert the index to positive? If you want to access the array, python does the access rollover by itself

Answer (score 20, accepted):

index = index modulo size

```
index = index % len(list)
```

For a list of size 4, it will have following values for given indices :

```
 4 -> 0
 3 -> 3
 2 -> 2
 1 -> 1 
 0 -> 0
-1 -> 3
-2 -> 2
-3 -> 1
-4 -> 0
```

Comment: you can also use `index %= len(list)`, it's the same: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

Answer (score 3):

If you try to "go back" starting with a non-negative index, you can also use

```
index = len(l) - index - 1
```

to compute the "index from the back".

This is how you have to do it in many other programming languages. Pythons negative indices are just syntactic sugar.

But if you really use negative indices, this dirty hack is a one-liner without `if` and `else`:

```
index = int(negative != 0 and negative + len(l))
```

Explanation:

- if `negative == 0` the result of the `and` expression is `False` which is converted to `0` by calling `int`.
- else the result of `and` is `negative + len`, see also [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html). The call to `int` then just does nothing.

This is good for learning Python, but I usually avoid such tricks. They are hard to read for you and others, and maybe you want to read your program in a few months again and you then you will wonder what this line is doing.

Answer (score 0):

A negative index is the same as subtracting from the length:

```
>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>> lst[-1] == lst[len(lst) - 1]
True
```

So you could get an always positive value with a small if statement:

```
i = -2
index = i if number >= 0 else len(lst) - i
```

In fact, you could use modulus to make an index wrap over back to 0 if the length is more than the length of the list:

```
# assuming length of list is 4
index = i % len(list)

# with i at 0:
0 % 4 == 0 # that works

# with i as -2
-2 % 4 == 2 # that works

# with i as 3:
3 % 4 == 3 % # that works
```

Comment: Yes, however my problem is on an index of 0:
`lst[0] == lst[len(lst) - 0]`
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Using the ternary if statement avoids this as the `else` part only evaluates if the index is *less* than 0, not 0 itself

Comment: @ducminh it's a different condition in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `~` complement operator. It will give you the inverse index as you require.

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> l[0]
'a'
>>> l[~0]
'd'
>>> l[~3]
'a'
>>> l[~-1]
'a'
>>> l[-1]
'd'
```